# Delete object from inner schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

How do I delete object from inner schema in mongoose?
I try to delete comments from the Holiday Schema, this is the holiday schema:

```
const holidaySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    comments: [commentSchema],
  },
)
const Holiday = mongoose.model("Holiday", holidaySchema);


export default Holiday;
```

and this is the comments schema:

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    action: { type: String },

    time: { type: String },

    name: { type: String },
    image: { type: String },

    content: { type: String },
    rating: { type: Number },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I try to delete a specific comment from the holidaySchema in this way:

```
holidayRouter.delete(
  "/:id/comments/:commentId",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const holiday = await Holiday.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $pull: { comments: { _id: req.params.commentId } } }
    );
if(holiday){
  console.log(holiday);
}
  })
);
```

the console:

[image]

and this is not working, do you know what I am doing wrong or what should I do?

thank you

Comment: query looks good, make sure you have that ids document in collection, what is the console in holiday?

Comment: the console shows a pending promise, can you find the problem?  [link](https://prnt.sc/11x05ta)

Comment: obviously it will show pending because you are not returning any response in api, i am talking about this `console.log(holiday);`, you can see this in your running node server console.

Comment: So what should I return there?

Comment: i don't know its up to your requirement that you have to give response or not, i am talking about this `console.log(holiday);` what this print in nodejs server console?

Comment: I want to delete the comment after I press the delete button, this is what I get from the console, it is not so clear to me:  [link](https://prnt.sc/11x6p2x)

Comment: It is actually deleted when you see `nModified: 1`, your record has been updated. you can check in database.

Comment: Thank you, now I see it is actually  work

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose converts the object into json, and we can customize that json which is returned.

```
 commentSchema.methods.toJSON = function(){
      const commentSchema = this.toObject()
    
      delete commentSchema.name
      delete commentSchema.rating
      
      return commentSchema 
    }
```

New the JSON which is returned will not have name and rating.